# How to get reference of a contained view controller in a table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a UITableViewController, in which there are several cells. Each cell has a UIContainerView, containing another view controller in the storyboard. Somehow I need to be able to refer to the cell from the embedded controller. I know there are many solutions online that involves using the `prepareForSegue` method, which I can't use in my case, because I could only implement such a method in the table view controller --- not the cell --- and I would not be able to identify which controller/cell is it since the cells are reused. Moreover, I am not even sure that I the instance of the cell is created when the method is called. What is a good way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you are using static cells or prototype one. ?? some code will be helpful.

Comment: Seems to be an odd design... Are your cells so complex to warrant a view controller in each? Are you properly resetting each view controller's view when the cell is **reused**?

Comment: I agree; why are you containing a view controller in each cell? I can't think of any reason to do this.

Comment: It's prototype cell. The only reason I'd do this it because I need to have a button bar, like they offer in XLPagerTabStrip library, in each cell to present some data. However, this library only offers a button bar controller, not a button bar scrollview or something. Thus, in order to achieve a button bar in each cell, I can think of no other ways. @Nicolas Miari